# Run Tkinter and TikTokLiveClient in the same time

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tiktok-api

Can you please tell me, if there exists a solution to run a Tkinter Gui and a TikTok live Client in the same time, because when I run the program only first of them starts.

```
import tkinter as tk
from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient

root = tk.Tk()
client = TikTokLiveClient(unique_id="<user_name>")

@client.on("like")
async def on_like(event):
    print(f"{event.user.nickname} liked the video")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
    client.run()
```

Comment: Why not run `tkinter` or `TikTokLiveClient` in another thread?

Comment: Does this help?     import tkinter as tk
    from TikTokLive.types.events import LikeEvent
    :
    :
    :
    
    
    @client.on("like")
    async def on_like(event: LikeEvent):
        print(f"{event.user.nickname} ----------> liked the video")
        new_like = event.user.nickname